# parser name defined to default :"parse" in yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

Hi i have written my lex file as below:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%%
[ \t (if) {return IF_TOKEN ;}
(else) {return ELSE_TOKEN ;}
(while) {return WHILE_TOKEN ;}
(FOR) {return FOR_TOKEN ;}
(BREAK) {return BREAK_TOKEN ;}
(float) {return FLOAT_TOKEN ;}
(int) {return INT_TOKEN ;}
(long) {return LONG_TOKEN ;}
(return) {return RETURN_TOKEN ;}
(defFunction) {return DEFFUNCTION_TOKEN ;}
(defClass) {return DEFCLASS_TOKEN ;}
(\() {return PAROPEN_TOKEN ;}
(\)) {return PARCLOS_TOKEN ;}
(\{) {return CBROPEN_TOKEN ;}
(\}) {return CBRCLOS_TOKEN ;}
(<) {return LESSTHN_TOKEN ;}
(>) {return GRTRTHN_TOKEN ;}
(=) {return EQUALTO_TOKEN ;}
(!=) {return NEQUALTO_TOKEN ;}
(\+) {return SUM_TOKEN ;}
(-) {return MINUS_TOKEN ;}
(\*) {return STAR_TOKEN ;}
(\/) {return SLASH_TOKEN ;}
(%) {return REMAIN_TOKEN ;}
(\[) {return BRAOPEN_TOKEN ;}
(\]) {return BRACLOS_TOKEN ;}
(";") {return SEMICOL_TOKEN ;}
([A-Za-z&_$][A-Za-z$_0-9]*) {return ID ;}
(0|[-]?[1-9][0-9]*) {return NUMBER ;}

. {return ERROR ;}

%%
int yywrap (void) {
   return 1;
}
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   yyin = fopen (argv[1], "r");
   yylex();
   fclose (yyin);
   return 0;
}
```

and i started to write my yacc file as below:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void) ;
    void yyerror(char *);   
%}

%token IF_TOKEN ELSE_TOKEN WHILE_TOKEN FOR_TOKEN BREAK_TOKEN FLOAT_TOKEN INT_TOKEN LONG_TOKEN RETURN_TOKEN DEFFUNCTION_TOKEN DEFCLASS_TOKEN PAROPEN_TOKEN PARCLOS_TOKEN CBROPEN_TOKEN CBR_CLOSTOKEN LESSTHN_TOKEN GRTRTHN_TOKEN EQUALTO_TOKEN NEQUALTO_TOKEN SUM_TOKEN MINUS_TOKEN STAR_TOKEN SLASH_TOKEN REMAIN_TOKEN BRAOPEN_TOKEN BRACLOS_TOKEN SEMICOL_TOKEN ID NUMBER ERROR

%%
program : expr ;
expr : NUMBER ;
%%

void yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void){
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

when i want to compile the yacc file with command:
    yacc example.y
it returns parser name defined to default :"parse"
i want to give it a number to check if it is correct then complete my yacc file.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like "yacc" produce a function called something other than "yyparse"?. (By the way, you probably have bison, and it makes a difference so you should check.)

Comment: i want when i compile the yacc file,i become able togive it an input and then the parser check it whether it is like the grammer which i write in the file or not?if it is not like as the grammer, give me an error.

Comment: Then you need to check the return value of `yyparse`. It returns 0 if the parse was successful. It also calls yyerror if it encounters an error, so you should also see an error message.

Comment: means i must change the main() to return yyparse() ?i changed it and again starting yacc example.y and again get the error,it does not let me to give it any input to check, it must wait for my input as the lexx wait.and after my input,gives the succsseful or other.

Comment: Please include your build procedure in your question (not in a comment). Thanks. (Also, I don't see how your tokens are defined in your scanner, since you don't #include the header produced by yacc/bison.)